# Phalcon castOnHydrate mysql boolean

Tags: php, types, casting, phalcon

I'm using Phalcon 3 and I'd like to return the real types when I query my database and it's better for API response. So I'm using this configuration :

`\Phalcon\Mvc\Model::setup(['castOnHydrate' => false]);`

And

```
$di->set('db', function () use ($config) {
    return new DbAdapter(array(
        'host' => $config->database->host,
        'username' => $config->database->username,
        'password' => $config->database->password,
        'dbname' => $config->database->dbname,
        'charset' => $config->database->charset,
        'options' => [
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false,
        ]
    ));
});
```

The problem is when mysql has a boolean type (`TINYINT` 0 or 1)

How can I convert this `TINYINT` to boolean ? Because `castOnHydrate` will just returns a integer 0 or 1. I'd like to get true / false.

Maybe there is a way to configure my models to specify which column is a boolean ?

Answer (score 0):

the quickest solution i know:

create a setter and getter for the column in model and protect the property

for example column `is_finished`

```php
/**
 *
 * @var integer
*/
protected $is_finished;

public function getIsFinished()
{
    return boolval($this->is_finished);
}

public function setIsFinished($value)
{
    $this->is_finished = intval($value);
}
```

now you can use the setter and getter or not it will be converted automatically

```php
$model = Model::findFirst();

$is_finished = $model->is_finished; // true|false

$is_finished = $model->getIsFinished(); // true|false

$model->is_finished = false; // 0

$model->setIsFinished(true); // 1
```

Comment: It could be a nice solution but sometimes I return directly the Model object. So I'll not  do `$model->getIsFinished();` every time. Maybe I should do something like this in the `afterFetch()` or use `db-models-metadata`

Comment: when you access the protected property ```is_finished``` it will automatically invoke the setter/getter for example accessing ```$model->is_finished = false;``` is identical to ```$model->setIsFinished(false);``` no need to use the setters/getters Phalcon will do it for you

Comment: Of course but as I said sometime I return to my API the object and I will not access to the property. Example : `$response->setJsonContent(Model::findFirst()); return $response`

Comment: absolutely in this case have to use ```beforeSave()``` and ```afterFetch()```. and here is something extra if you use these methods as i do like for caching in base model and don't want to override them you can override ```Model::jsonSerialize()``` it will call return a call to ```toArray()``` you can figure something from there. btw this issue came up in github #13141 hope this helps